# WSImport over SSL with fake (dev) certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, webservice-client, wsimport

Recently I spent couple of hours trying to get WSImport working on web service that is hosted over HTTPS, with fake certificate (dev deployment).

I tried to use windows version of `wsimport.exe`, from Java 8 jdk.

I specified option `-XdisableSSLHostnameVerification`, but it kept complaining about wrong certificate. 
That is true, certificate is not valid, but in dev environment it should be acceptable.

I did not find easy way to make wsimport to skip certificate check.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I got a solution, using wrapper class.

I think it makes sense to share the solution. 
Hope it will save some someone's time for better purposes.

The solution (assuming that java is installed in `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40`):

1. How to compile

   `"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\javac" -cp "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\lib\tools.jar" WSImportSSLByPass.java`
2. How to use

   `"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java" -cp "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\lib\tools.jar";. WSImportSSLByPass %wsimport args%`
3. The code

to be put into `WSImportSSLByPass.java`

```
    import java.security.KeyManagementException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

    import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
    import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
    import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
    import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

    public class WSImportSSLByPass {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{
            configureBypassSSL();
            com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(args);
        }

        private static void configureBypassSSL() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                KeyManagementException {
            SSLContext ssl_ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            TrustManager[] trust_mgr = get_trust_mgr();
            ssl_ctx.init(null, // key manager
                    trust_mgr, // trust manager
                    new SecureRandom()); // random number generator
            SSLSocketFactory sf = ssl_ctx.getSocketFactory();

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sf);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new DummyHostVerifier());
        }

        private static TrustManager[] get_trust_mgr() {
            TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String t) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String t) {
                }
            } };
            return certs;
        }
    }
    class DummyHostVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

        public boolean verify(String name, SSLSession sess) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This really helped me. Thank and it saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case of 2-way ssl handshake, we can modify the WSImportSSLByPass class like this

```
    import com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport;

public class OCBWSImport {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");

        //Certificate for 2-way handshake
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:\\tuanpa\\yourp12file.p12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password of p12 file");

        //Hostname checking bypass
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
                new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {

            public boolean verify(String hostname,
                    javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                //return hostname.equals("192.168.1.10");
                return true;
            }
        });
        WsImport.main(args);
    }

}
```